# Git bring branch up to date

Tags: git, merge

I have a git workflow that involves at least two branches, "master" and "staging". When I'm content with what I've put into master, I want to push it to a staging server for others to review, and for that to happen, I need to bring the "staging" branch up to date with the "master" branch.

Currently, I have to do this:

```
git checkout staging
git merge master
git checkout master
```

Is there any way for me to merge my current branch *into* the staging branch in one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the merge fails you probably want to handle the conflicts. And as such you need to be checked out at the staging branch, otherwise where will the conflicting files be?

What you could do is create a shell alias for the process:

```
alias updateStage="git checkout staging && git merge master && git checkout master"
```

In case the merge fails `git-merge` will return `1` and it won't attempt to checkout master back, leaving you free to resolve the conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care what is currently on `staging` and only want to **force** it to point to the same commit as master:

```
git update-ref refs/heads/staging refs/heads/master
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-ref